# i tried running npx hardhat testbut kee[ getting this error, i need help i stuck here and i need to progress on this

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

error message

```
 Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contra.6.0)
```

test.js

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("NFTMarket", function () {
  it("Should create and execute market sales", async function () {
    const Market = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarket")
    const market = await Market.deploy()
    await Market.deploy()
    const marketAddress = market.address

    const NFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT")
    const nft = await NFT.deploy(marketAddress)
    await NFT.deploy()
    const nftContractAddress = nft.address

    let listingPrice = await market.getListingPrice()
    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

    const auctionPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'ethers')

    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation.com")
    await nft.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation2.com")

    await market.createMarketItem(nftContractAddress, 1, auctionPrice, {value: listingPrice})
    await market.createMarketItem(nftContractAddress, 2, auctionPrice, {value: listingPrice})

    const [_, buyerAddress] = await ethers.getSigners()

    await market.connect(buyerAddress).createMarketSale(nftContractAddress, 1, {value: auctionPrice})

    const items = await market.fetchMarketItems()

    console.log('items: ', items)
  }); 
});
```

my contract code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract NFTMarket is ReentrancyGuard {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    address payable owner;
    uint256 listingPrice = 0.025 ether;

    constructor () {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    struct MarketItem {
      uint itemId;
      address nftContract;
      uint256 tokenId;
      address payable seller;
      address payable owner;
      uint256 price;
      bool sold;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

    event MarketItemCreated (
      uint indexed itemId,
      address indexed nftContract,
      uint256 indexed tokenId,
      address seller,
      address owner,
      uint256 price,
      bool sold
    );

    function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return listingPrice;
    }

    function createMarketItem(
        address nftContract,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price

      ) public payable nonReentrant {
        require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
        require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");

        _itemIds.increment();
        uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();

        idToMarketItem[itemId] = MarketItem(
            itemId,
            nftContract,
            tokenId,
            payable(msg.sender),
            payable(address(0)),
            price,
            false
        );

        IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

        emit MarketItemCreated(
            itemId,
            nftContract,
            tokenId,
            msg.sender,
            address(0),
            price,
            false
        );

      }


      function createMarketSale(
          address nftContract,
          uint256 itemId
      ) public payable nonReentrant {
          uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
          uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
          require(msg.value == price, "please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

          idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
          IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
          idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
          idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
          _itemsSold.increment();
          payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
      }

     function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint itemCount = _itemIds.current();
        uint unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
        uint currentIndex = 0;

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
         if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(this)) {
           uint currentId = i + 1;
           MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
           items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
           currentIndex += 1;
         }
        }
        return items;
     }

     function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
      uint itemCount = 0;
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
          itemCount += 1;
        }
      }

       MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
       for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
           uint currentId = i + 1;
           MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
           items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
           currentIndex += 1;
        }
       }
      return items;
    }

    function fetchItemsCreated() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
      uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
      uint itemCount = 0;
      uint currentIndex = 0;

      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
          itemCount += 1;
        }
      }

      MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
      for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
          uint currentId = i + 1;
          MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
          items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
          currentIndex += 1;
        }
      }
      return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line after you deploy it:

```
await NFT.deploy()
```

should be

```
await NFT.deployed()
```

same with the Market contract